# How to eliminate all levels of lists in LISP

Tags: list, lisp

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to remove nested parentheses in LISP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680864/how-to-remove-nested-parentheses-in-lisp)

This is my second quick-and-silly question about LISP, but I am kind of stuck. I need to access all the nodes in a list with several levels. I need something like:

```
>> (get-symbols '(A (B (C D) E )))
(A B C D E)
```

I don't care about the order. How would you do that? I prefer code intuitivity rather than efficency.

Thanks

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680864/how-to-remove-nested-parentheses-in-lisp

Comment: "nested parenthesis". I didn't think on that way to put it in, that's why i didn't find that one. If it works for me, and I hope so, should I remove this question?

Comment: "flattening nested lists" is the proper description. Your question is a duplicate. Delete it if you want to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From OnLisp:

```
(defun flatten (tree)
  (if (atom tree)
      (mklist tree)
    (nconc (flatten (car tree))
       (if (cdr tree) (flatten (cdr tree))))))
```

Answer (score 4):

What you need is the `flatten` function for lists. Look it up.

Comment: I can't find that function in Common Lisp (I forgot to indicate which Lisp version i have to use)

Answer (score 0):

```
 (defun get-symbols (lst)
        (when lst
           (if (atom lst) (list lst)
               (append (get-symbols (car lst))
                       (get-symbols (cdr lst))))))
```