# Common Lisp - flatting a list that may contain symbols

Tags: list, common-lisp, quote, flatten

This is #7 of of [99 Lisp problems](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/L-99_Ninety-Nine_Lisp_Problems.html): transform a list, possibly holding lists as elements into a `flat' list by replacing each list with its elements (recursively). I have tried several solutions, e.g from #[2680864](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680864/how-to-remove-nested-parentheses-in-lisp) or [from here](http://www.ic.unicamp.br/~meidanis/courses/mc336/2006s2/funcional/p07.lisp). They all work, but I run into a problem if I am flattening a list containing a quoted element. E.g.:

```
> '(a 'b c)
(A 'B C)

> '(a (quote b) c)
(A 'B C)

> (flatten '(a 'b c))
(A QUOTE B C)
```

In the latter case I would like to get:

```
(A 'B C)
```

It seems that the internal representation of ' gets in the way for this task! SBCL, CLISP, ECL, ... they all behave the same way.

Comment: The problem you are experiencing are due to the fact that the quote-symbol (') is converted to (quote ...) when LISP reads the expression. To make it easier to read the output, a corresponding conversion occurs when LISP prints your list. Therefore, there is no way to distinguish the two when letting LISP read it as a list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoted elements in a list? That usually does not make sense. Why would you have it quoted?

`(a b c)` is a list of three symbols. Why would you quote elements in the list? like in `(a 'b c)`? Why? What would be the purpose of the quote?

In Common Lisp `'` is a readmacro which expands `'a` into `(QUOTE A)`. Since this is a normal list, a typical flatten operation will collect the symbols `QUOTE` and `A` into the flat list. This is because a flatten function typicall checks whether something is an atom or not. If you don't want this, your flatten function needs to check if something is an atom or a two-element list with `QUOTE` as its first symbol.

But as I said above, the default usage is just to flatten symbols, since quoted symbols are usually not useful inside a list. You need to extend the flatten function otherwise.

For example:

```
(defun flatten (l &key (test #'atom))
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((funcall test l) (list l))
        (t (loop for a in l nconc (flatten a :test test)))))


CL-USER > (flatten '(a (('b) c) ('d) )
                   :test (lambda (item)
                           (or (atom item)
                               (and (eq (first item) 'quote)
                                    (null (cddr item))))))

(A (QUOTE B) C (QUOTE D))
```

Comment: `(defun flatten (l)
  (cond ((null l) nil)
        ((atom l) (list l))
        ((equal l (list 'QUOTE (second l))) (cdr l))
        (t (loop for a in l appending (flatten a)))))` This gives me `(A B C)`. I guess there is no way to get `(A 'B C)` if I have `(flatten '(A 'B C))` I have no control on the list that gets passed to flatten. I think this solves my problem, although there is a slight asymmetry :)

Comment: @Antonio Bonifati: see the added example