# How to remove double parentheses and leave only the nested lists in lisp?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, nested-lists, parentheses

For example, convert from this:

```
((((7 8) (0 H 0))) (((11 12))))
```

to the following:

```
((7 8) (0 H 0) (11 12))
```

not `(7 8 0 H 0 11 12)` !!
Thank you.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39071217/every-second-bracket-lisp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove nested parentheses in LISP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680864/how-to-remove-nested-parentheses-in-lisp)

Comment: No it is not a duplicate, and the first one is not answered :)

Answer (score 0):

```
0: (MYSTERIOUS ((((7 8) (0 H 0))) (((11 12))) (((A B) (C D))) ((D E F))))
  1: (MAGIC (((7 8) (0 H 0))))
    2: (MAGIC ((7 8) (0 H 0)))
      3: (MAGIC (7 8))
      3: MAGIC returned ((7 8))
      3: (MAGIC (0 H 0))
      3: MAGIC returned ((0 H 0))
    2: MAGIC returned ((7 8) (0 H 0))
  1: MAGIC returned ((7 8) (0 H 0))
  1: (MAGIC (((11 12))))
    2: (MAGIC ((11 12)))
      3: (MAGIC (11 12))
      3: MAGIC returned ((11 12))
    2: MAGIC returned ((11 12))
  1: MAGIC returned ((11 12))
  1: (MAGIC (((A B) (C D))))
    2: (MAGIC ((A B) (C D)))
      3: (MAGIC (A B))
      3: MAGIC returned ((A B))
      3: (MAGIC (C D))
      3: MAGIC returned ((C D))
    2: MAGIC returned ((A B) (C D))
  1: MAGIC returned ((A B) (C D))
  1: (MAGIC ((D E F)))
    2: (MAGIC (D E F))
    2: MAGIC returned ((D E F))
  1: MAGIC returned ((D E F))
0: MYSTERIOUS returned ((7 8) (0 H 0) (11 12) (A B) (C D) (D E F))
```

Comment: @Sylwester `(flatten '((((7 8) (0 H 0))) (((11 12)))))` gives `(7 8 0 H 0 11 12)`, which is different from the (possibly underspecified) problem.

Answer (score 0):

if the nesting level is constant, like in the example, you could simply do this:

```
CL-USER> (mapcan #'car '((((7 8) (0 H 0))) (((11 12)))))
((7 8) (0 H 0) (11 12))
```

Comment: You are mutating constant values. You have no guarantee what's going to happen.

Comment: should i copy the car instead? `(mapcan (lambda (x) (copy (car x))) ...)` or something else?