# multiplying each element of a list with each element of another list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, multiplication

i want to write a function that accepts 2 lists as argument and return multiplication of them in a list.
like this:

(3 4) (3 5 6) => (9 15 18 12  20 24)

this is the code that i've came up with but i receive an error which is telling me that i have too few arguments for map.

```
(defun multip (lst lst2)
    ;this is a function to flatten the result
   (defun flatten (tree)
     (let ((result '()))
       (labels ((scan (item)
           (if (listp item)
               (map nil #'scan item)
               (push item result))))
                  (scan tree))
                       (nreverse result)))
(flatten (map (lambda (i) (map (lambda (j) (* i j)) lst )) lst2))
 )

   (write  (multip '(3 4 6) '(3 2) ))
```

i can not understand what am i doing wrong. i appreciate your comment.

Comment: FYI, you can use use map-product:   `(alexandria:map-product #'* '(3 4) '(3 5 6))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `mapcar` instead of `map`:

```
(mapcar (lambda (i) (mapcar (lambda (j) (* i j)) lst )) lst2))
```

These are two different functions: `mapcar` maps a function on one or more lists, and requires at least two arguments, while `map` is the equivalent but for any kind of sequences (e.g. vectors), and requires an additional argument specifying the type of the result. See the reference for `map` [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_map.htm#map), and the reference for `mapcar` [here](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcar).

**Style**

You are using a `defun` inside another `defun`: this is not good style, since every time `multip` is called it redefines globally the function `flatten`. You should either define `flatten` externally, only once, or use a local declaration of function with `flet` or `labels` (as for the internal function `scan` inside `flatten`.)

For alternative and more simple definitions of `flatten`, you can see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2680864/how-to-remove-nested-parentheses-in-lisp) in SO.

Comment: yeah you are right about the style, i will read the resources that you introduced to me. thanks again.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to flatten the list, if you create a flat list.

Use MAPCAN:

```
CL-USER 4 > (flet ((mult (a b)
                     (mapcan #'(lambda (a1)
                                 (mapcar (lambda (b1) (* a1 b1))
                                         b))
                             a)))
              (mult '(3 4) '(3 5 6)))
(9 15 18 12 20 24)
```