# find the position of an atom in list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, lispworks

I have this board with atom T and I wanna get is position in list and sub-list

```
(defun board ()
"position of T: i=0 e j=9"
  '(
  ;; 0  1  2  3  4  5 6  7  8  9
    (96 25 54 89 21 8 36 14 41 T) ;; 0
    (78 47 56 23 5 NIL 13 12 26 60) ;; 1
    (0 27 17 83 34 93 74 52 45 80) ;; 2
    (69 9 77 95 55 39 91 73 57 30) ;; 3
    (24 15 22 86 1 11 68 79 76 72) ;; 4
    (81 48 32 2 64 16 50 37 29 71) ;; 5
    (99 51 6 18 53 28 7 63 10 88) ;; 6
    (59 42 46 85 90 75 87 43 20 31) ;; 7
    (3 61 58 44 65 82 19 4 35 62) ;; 8
    (33 70 84 40 66 38 92 67 98 97);; 9
    )
)
```

Function to get line and cell from board

```
(defun line (x board)
  (nth x board))

(defun cell-board (x y board)
  (nth y (line x board)))

(defun column (index board)
  (cond ((not (numberp index)) nil)
        ((< index 0) nil)
        (t (mapcar #'(lambda (line &aux (n-column (nth index line))) n-column) board))))
```

Function that receives the board and returns the position (i j) where the "T" is. If "T" is not on the board, NIL should be returned.

```
(defun find-T-position (board)

 )
```

you can teste and see the result here https://ideone.com/GQIePI

> (print "position : " (find-T-position (board)))

the result correct should be

> (0 9)

[image]

Comment: And the question is? Good luck with your homework btw

Comment: @Sylwester,  this not homework, it´s a project and I don´t wanna put much code, only the goal, the rest I made and I update the question and thanks to vote for question is close

Comment: It is still not a question anywhere in the post. Also your rows start at 0 while you're columns start at 1.

Comment: the column in image start 1 but in project start 0

Comment: so correct, edit or update the question and maybe answer and we finish this

Comment: @RenataPSouza sounds like you want to use `position` or `position-if`... Here is a link to their page in the HyperSpec http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_pos_p.htm. Of course your case is 2 dimensional so a simple application won't suffice - but it still seems like the right direction to try...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the answer in this question [Lisp position of nested list element with children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58618184/lisp-position-of-nested-list-element-with-children) and it´s work perfectly

```
(defun my-position (elm tree &optional (start 0))
  "find the generalized position of elm inside tree.
   Parameters: elm - element to be found
               tree - a list of atoms and lists in which to search the element
               start - the tentative position"      
  (cond ((null tree) nil)       ; element not present => nil
        ((atom (first tree))    ; if the first element is an atom, then
         (if (eql elm (first tree)) ; if equal to element, found
             (list start)           ; return position start
             ;; otherwise, recur on rest of list incrementing the tentative position
             (my-position elm (rest tree) (1+ start))))
        ;; otherwise, the first element is a list,
        ;; try to find it inside, with a recursive call
        (t (let ((pos (my-position elm (first tree) 0)))
             (if pos ; if not nil the element has been found
                 (cons start pos) ; return the current position followed by the position inside the list
                 ; otherwise recur on rest of list incrementing the tentative position
                 (my-position elm (rest tree) (1+ start)))))))
```

> and my function find-t-position just call the function my-position
>   with element 'T and the board and return the position of element 'T in
>   list

```
(defun find-T-position (board)
     (my-position ('T board))
```

you can see the correct result https://ideone.com/DOIOoB

Answer (score 1):

The `board` function tries to call a literal list as-if it was a function. The quote is misplaced.

The `find-t-position` function has no body. 
If you add more code and an actual question you will have better feedback.

Hint: either T is in current row `(car board)`, or you need to search the board `(cdr board)`; test often to spot errors.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun find-t (rows)
  (let* ((col nil)
         (row (position-if (lambda (r) (setf col (position t r))) rows)))
    (values row col)))
```

Some tests:

```
[1]> (find-t nil)
NIL ;
NIL
[2]> (find-t '(()))
NIL ;
NIL
[3]> (find-t '((0)))
NIL ;
NIL
[4]> (find-t '((t)))
0 ;
0
[5]> (find-t '((0 t)))
0 ;
1
[6]> (find-t '((0 t 0)))
0 ;
1
[7]> (find-t '((0 0 t)))
0 ;
2
[8]> (find-t '((0 0 0)))
NIL ;
NIL
[9]> (find-t '((0 0 0)  
               (t 0 0)))
1 ;
0
[10]> (find-t '((0 0 0)
               (t 0 t)))
1 ;
0
[11]> (find-t '((0 0 0)
               (0 0 t)))
1 ;
2
[12]> (find-t '((0 0 t)
               (0 0 t)))
0 ;
2
```

Comment: thanks you answer is good and correct but **the use of variables
set instructions, setq, setf, cycles, destructive functions**, or any
functions with side effects is strongly discouraged as it usually denotes a low
technical quality because it´s Common Lisp Hyperspec

Comment: maybe you can help me with this question to [swap or shuffle list without duplicate element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59022738/shuffle-list-without-duplicate-number-in-lisp?noredirect=1#comment104292896_59022738) between 0 and 99 and I have the list, I need just swap or shuffle, please see the question